# Как исправить ошибку несуществующего столбца в таблицы, хотя до этого столбец с таким именем был создан?

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть код на python, я пытаюсь сохранить данные с помощью этого кода

```
def sav_dataframe(id_thermostat, temperature_input,\
                  temperature_weather, date,
                  temperature_radiator, windspeed,\
                  set_temperature, heating_time):
    conn, cursor = open_conn("dataframe.db")
cursor.execute(f"""
        INSERT INTO dataframe (id_thermostat, temperature_input, temperature_weather, date, temperature_radiator, windspeed, set_temperature, heating_time)
        VALUES ({id_thermostat}, {temperature_input}, {temperature_weather}, {date}, {temperature_radiator}, {windspeed}, {set_temperature}, {heating_time});
        """)
```

```
def open_conn(file_db):
   db_path = os.path.join(file_db)
   conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
   cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Таблица имеет такие колонки

```
def create_table_dataframe():
    create_sql_data = "id_thermostat TEXT,"\
        "temperature_input REAL,"\
        "temperature_weather REAL,"\
        "date DATE,"\
        "temperature_radiator REAL,"\
        "windspeed REAL,"\
        "set_temperature",\
        "heating_time REAL"

    db = SQLiteDatabase("dataframe.db")
    db.create_table_if_not_exists("dataframe", create_sql_data)
    db.disconnect()
```

Создание таблицы происходит в другом методе

```
def create_table_if_not_exists(table_name, schema):
    cursor.execute(f'''
                CREATE TABLE {table_name} {schema}
            ''')
```

При вызове функции `sav_dataframe()` вызывается эта ошибка

> ```
> table dataframe has no column named id_thermostat
> ```

Comment: Вы показали не таблицу, а код создания таблицы. А вы проверяли, что **уже созданная** таблица действительно имеет колонку id_thermostat?

Answer (score 0):

Когда говорит, что такой столбец не существует, так не существует.

Ваша функция `create_table_dataframe()` очень чудесная. Кажется, что вы просто где-то взяли какой-то код и думали, что он будет работать. Это не код для пакета `sqlite3`.

Вероятно, не существуют ни другие столбцы, но ошибка возникла при первом не существующем.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что столбец id_thermostat не был создан при создании таблицы dataframe.

Чтобы исправить это, нужно:

> Добавить id_thermostat TEXT при создании таблицы:

```
create_sql_data = "id_thermostat TEXT," + rest_of_columns
```

> Убедиться, что тип данных для id_thermostat в sav_dataframe()
> совпадает с определением столбца. Так как он определен как TEXT, нужно
> передавать строку, а не число:

```
id_thermostat="therm1", # строка
```

> вместо

```
id_thermostat=1, # число
```

> Если таблица уже создана без столбца id_thermostat, его можно добавить
> командой:

```
ALTER TABLE dataframe ADD COLUMN id_thermostat TEXT
```

> Перед повторным вызовом sav_dataframe().